# Is there a way I can replace an element of an array based on its value and not element number with two new elements in the array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm programming in Perl, and I'm in a situation where I have an array such as `@contents=(A,S,D,F,M,E)` and I want to replace the element `M` with two new elements `X` and `Y`, such as `@contents` would equal `(A,S,D,F,X,Y,E)`.

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurrences of `M`, or just the first, or are you content to assume that there's only one?

Comment: @Woody If you consider your question answered, please consider accepting one of the answers by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).

```
@contents = map { $_ eq 'M' ? ('X','Y') : $_ } @contents;
```

Or you can use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
for (0 .. $#contents) {
    if ($contents[$_] eq 'M') {
        splice @contents, $_, 1, 'X', 'Y';
    }
}
```

You can also simplify further by using [`keys @contents`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) as the list of indexes, if you are using perl version 5.12 and up.

Comment: You should add a note that `keys @contents` only works on 5.12 or newer versions of Perl.

Comment: @BradGilbert So added. So many of the handy features that seem so simple need these silly notes.

Comment: It is only because it is still so new. There were things added in [5.6](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html) that we take for granted. Like [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#%22our%22-declarations), [3 arg `open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#open()-with-more-than-two-arguments), and [`binmode fh, ':crlf'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#binmode()-can-be-used-to-set-%3acrlf-and-%3araw-modes).

Comment: @BradGilbert It's not like it's beta, though. 5.12 has been out, what, 2 years, and 5.10 4 years. There must be a better way to handle backwards compatibility so that people actually update their perl binaries.

Answer (score 2):

The command you are looking for is [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;

my @contents = qw(A S D F M E);
my $match    = 'M';
my @replace  = qw(X Y);
my $arrlen   = @contents;

for (my $i = 0; $i < $arrlen; $i++)
{
    if ($contents[$i] eq $match)
    {
        splice (@contents, $i, 1, @replace);
        last;
    }
}

print "$_\n" foreach (@contents);
```

Comment: Some tips: `use warnings` is the recommended pragma, as it allows for lexical scoping. Use perl style for loops, e.g. `my $arrlen = $#contents; for my $i (0 .. $arrlen) ...` instead of C-style for loops. Why are you using taint checking? Using `last` will only replace the first occurrence of the match. You may be interested in looking into [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html). `say for @contents` is rather better looking. +1 for using both strict and warnings, though.

Comment: Thank for looking my code over for me.  My intent was to make the code more readable and easier to digest for people unfamiliar with perl, as the most common complaint I hear from people new to perl is obscure syntax.  Potatoe, potatoe, I suppose.  I am using `last` to break out of the loop as the sample code in the original post did not indicate that it needed to match more than once (only 1 'M' in the original array).  If that were not the case, then yes, I would recommend removing the statement `last`.

Comment: It's only obscure if you don't know it. I find that I can read many  people's perl better than I can read their english. =)

Comment: @TLP Perl has a very well-defined grammar, English on the other hand is very much not well-defined.